# UISlider in UITableViewCell won't work in iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uislider

I have strange issue with `UISlider` it works perfect in iOS 6.0 but in iOS 5.1 it doesn't work. I have used storyboard for the `UIViewController` and `UITableView` has 4 kinds of cells. Everything works fine in iOS 6.0 but only the cells which have **UISlider won't work properly in iOS 5.1.**

The exact issue is that the valueChanged method is getting called but **the UISlider Thumb is kind of stuck at the minimum value which i have provided.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have You Seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691523/ios-5-1-swipe-gesture-hijacked-by-uisplitviewcontroller-how-to-avoid

Comment: Its a UIViewController with a UITableView in a UIPopOverController. Its not a UISplitViewController and UIViewController doesn't have that property because its specific with UISplitViewController